# How to update in SQL to get distinct tuples / not to violate a unique constraint

Tags: mysql, merge, sql-update, duplicates, unique-constraint

I have a mapping table with a unique contraint on the tuple `(c_id, t_id)`.

Here's some sample data to illustrate the situation:

```
id  c_id    t_id  
----------------
1   10      2
2   10      3
3   10      7
4   12      2
5   13      3
```

I wrote a merge function for `t_ids` (x,y -> z OR x,y -> x).
If my content (`c_id`) has both `t_ids`, then I'm of course violating the constraint by using this statement:

```
UPDATE mapping_table
SET t_id = '$target_tid'
WHERE t_id = '$t1_id' OR t_id = '$t2_id';
```

The result would be:

```
id  c_id    t_id
----------------
1   10      4
2   10      4       /* violates unique constraint */
3   10      7
```

Now I came up with this:

```
/* delete one of the duplicate entries */
DELETE FROM mapping_table
WHERE   ( SELECT count(c_id)
          FROM mapping_table
          WHERE t_id = '$t1_id' OR t_id = '$t2_id'
        ) > 1;

/* update the remaining row */
UPDATE mapping_table
SET t_id = '$target_tid'
WHERE t_id = '$t1_id' OR t_id = '$t2_id';
```

Now I'm getting the following error:
`You can't specify target table 'mapping_table' for update in FROM clause`

My questions are:

1. What's exactly wrong here? Is the `DELETE` statement seen as an update and cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause?
2. This there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the delete statement, but mysql does not like the same table to ocuur in a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are having is a peculiarity of MySQL.  You can get around this with a double set of subqueries:

```
DELETE FROM mapping_table
WHERE  (select *
        from ( SELECT count(c_id)
               FROM mapping_table
               WHERE t_id = '$t1_id' OR t_id = '$t2_id'
             ) > 1
        ) t
```

To fix your problem though, just remove all ids except for the minimum.  I think this might also work:

```
delete from mapping_table
where id > (select minid from (select min(id) from mapping_table mt2
                               where mt2.c_id = mapping_table.c_id and
                                     mt2.t_id = mapping_table.t_id
                              )
           )
```

You can also store the list of ids in a temporary table, and use that in the query:

```
create temporary table minids as
     select c_id, t_id, min(id) as minid
     from mapping_table
     group by c_id, t_id;

delete from mapping_table
where exists (select 1 from minids
              where mt2.c_id = mapping_table.c_id and
                    mt2.t_id = mapping_table.t_id and
                    mt2.minid > mapping_table.id
             )
```

Comment: I had some issues with your statements being incomplete and having syntax errors, but since your suggestions pushed me into the right direction I accept your answer. -- Check my answer to see what I really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM mapping_table
    WHERE   ( SELECT count(c_id)
      FROM mapping_table
      WHERE t_id = '$t1_id' OR t_id = '$t2_id'
      Having count(c_id) > 1
    );
```

EDIT:

try this in your update statment

```
 UPDATE mapping_table
 SET t_id = '$target_tid'
WHERE t_id in (select t_id from mapping_table where t_id= '$t1_id' OR t_id = '$t2_id')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still producing the same error. `You can't specify target table 'mapping_table' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this solution. The performance is probably amazingly low, but at least I found a working solution (and learnt something).

```
/* actually delete rows that will become duplicate after the update */
DELETE FROM mt1 USING mapping_table AS mt1 WHERE id IN (

    /* sub-query to allow `mapping_table` in the DELETE statement */
    SELECT * FROM (

        /* select ids/rows with one t_id available */
        SELECT id
        FROM mapping_table AS mt2
        WHERE mt2.tag_id = $t1_id AND c_id IN (

            /* select ids/rows with both t_id available */
            SELECT c_id
            FROM mapping_table AS mt3
            WHERE mt3.c_id = mt2.c_id AND mt3.tag_id = $t2_id)

    /* alias needed for every derived table */
    ) as mres
)

/* Update to merge t_ids */
UPDATE mapping_table
SET t_id = '$target_id'
WHERE t_id = '$t1_id' OR t_id = '$t2_id';
```