# Multiple row update results in unique "Integrity constraint violation"

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, unique-constraint

I have a unique constraint on SKU column in a variant table. I have a form where I can edit multiple variants with respective SKUs. The classic problem ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043316/how-to-update-in-sql-to-get-distinct-tuples-not-to-violate-a-unique-constraint) and [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207574/how-to-swap-values-of-two-rows-in-mysql-without-violating-unique-constraint)) is as follows (and affects MySQL):

Suppose you have two rows with values:

- *SKU1*
- *SKU2*

If you **swap** two values in an edited collection, *unique validation will succeed* and doctrine will issue two updates.

The first one will set *SKU1* to *SKU2* and will immediately fail unique constraint because there are duplicate values *SKU2* and *SKU2*.

- *SKU1* -> *SKU2* (unique constaint fail)
- *SKU2*

What is the best way to solve it in Symfony 2.3 Form and Doctrine 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

Create a third value:

- SKU1 --> _SKU1
- SKU2 --> SKU1
- _SKU1 --> SKU2

Comment: Yes, this is one of the possible solutions. The other one is to begin transaction, lock table, disable unique constraint, update, enable, unlock, commit. But maybe there is even cleaner solution?